# Take href from element and add to the src attribute of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, attr

How can I take the href link found in the div class `.image1`

```
<div class="image1">
    <a href="/images/productA.jpg"> </a>
</div>
```

And add it to the image `src` here…

```
<ul class="example">
    <li class="GalleryImage1"> <img src="" > </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Something to clarify - as the class "image1" can be applied to multiple objects, doing a $(".image1 a") may return an array of <a href> objects. Do you just take the first object you find and use the href source of that?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this :

```
var href = $('.image1 a').attr('href');

//if you want the href to all img in the ul
$('.example li img').attr('src',href);

//if you want the href only to this li
$('.example .GalleryImage1 img').attr('src',href);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method of jQuery.

Find the selectors for the href, do `my_href = $(your_selector).attr("href")`, and then change the `src` attr on the `img` element with `$(img_selector).attr("src", my_href)`

Comment: This worked. I am using Adobe Business Catalyst and wanted to bypass their Lightbox gallery and use my own. I was successfully able to pull the url from each lightbox image and add it to my gallery.

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped.